# Stream filter on list keeping some of the filtered values

Tags: java, filter, stream, java-stream

So I need to filter a list of items where

Item definition:

```
{
 id, category, title
}
```

Category can be T (title) or K(keyword) of type string. The problem is that sometimes we have items of category K that can have title repetition.

So I need to filter all of the items that are of category K to keep only one of them if there is title repetition.

```
    public List<Item> findSuggestions(String req) {
        List<Item> items = service.findSuggestions(req);
        Predicate<Item> isTitle = item -> item.getCategory().equals("T");
        Predicate<Item> differentTitle = Utils.distinctByKey(Item::getTitle);
        Predicate<Item> isKeyword = item -> item.getCategory().equals("K");
        List<Item> result = items.stream()
                .filter(isTitle)
                .filter(differentTitle).collect(Collectors.toList());
        result.addAll(items.stream().filter(isKeyword).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return result;
    }
```

I would like to simplify this, without having to separate the logic into two different filters.

Comment: `Predicate<Item> finalFilter = isTitle.and(differentTitle).or(isKeyword)`?

Comment: Very good solution ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Amongalen, use OR AND operations of Predicates

```
public List<Item> findSuggestions(String req) {
            List<Item> items = service.findSuggestions(req);
            Predicate<Item> isTitle = item -> item.getCategory().equals("T");
            Predicate<Item> differentTitle = Utils.distinctByKey(Item::getValue);
            Predicate<Item> isKeyword = item -> item.getCategory().equals("K");
            return items.stream().filter(isTitle.and(differentTitle).
                    or(isKeyword)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
```